# hidesBarsOnSwipe method not working when swiping my collection view

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

I tried implementing the simple one line of code shown below into my viewDidLoad in order to have my navigaion bar hide when a user swipes on my collectionview. However the action only works when i swipe from my navigation bar, no where else. I would like it to hide on swipe from my collection view which of course takes up most of the view.

[A mini video of the issue](https://youtu.be/IPnn8eI08m8)

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
navigationController?.hidesBarsOnSwipe = true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the view controller embedded in the navigation controller?

Comment: Could you please share your storyboard setup and viewcontroller code please? I've created one simple UICollectionView and adding "hidesBarsOnSwipe" in viewdidload works

Answer (score 0):

> Swift 4, Swift 5:

- Hide your navigation bar when you scroll upside and similarly show when you scroll downside.
- `scrollViewDidScroll()` method will get called every time when you scroll your `CollectionView`, `TableView`, `ScrollView` etc.

Try this code:

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
   //Check the scroll direction here 
    if(scrollView.panGestureRecognizer.translation(in: scrollView.superview).y > 0) {
        print("Show")
        self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: true)
        self.navigationController?.setToolbarHidden(false, animated: true)
    }
    else {
        print("Hide")
        self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: true)
        self.navigationController?.setToolbarHidden(true, animated: true)
    }
}
```